# JSON parsing of ClusterRole in Go is not working

Tags: go, kubernetes

I have a problem parsing the metadata in ClusterRole object from Json in Go.

I made this example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/rbac"
)

func main() {
    clusterDemo := rbac.ClusterRole{}

    clusterRolesRaw := `{
        "apiVersion": "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1",
        "kind": "ClusterRole",
        "metadata": {
            "creationTimestamp": "2021-01-21T08:07:13Z",
            "managedFields": [],
            "name": "kubeadm:get-nodes",
            "resourceVersion": "220",
            "uid": "c78a8b10-cd20-4b64-8e4d-4f7f758c7b65"
        },
        "rules": []
    }`
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(clusterRolesRaw), &clusterDemo)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("unmarshal file: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Name: %s\n", clusterDemo.Name)
    fmt.Printf("Kind: %s\n", clusterDemo.Kind)
}
```

Run it with

```
# go get -v ./... 
# go run <filename>
Name: 
Kind: ClusterRole
```

As you can see, the Kind field is parsed, but the Name field (part of the metadata) is not.

My question is why? It looks like the nested structure is not parsed.

Any help is appreciated, I think I am missing something

Comment: In https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/rbac#ClusterRole, `metav1.ObjectMeta` is an inline/embedded field. So I don't think the JSON should have fields nested under `metadata`?

Comment: This is what I get from "kubectl get clusterroles -o json"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your import from `"k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/rbac"` to `rbac "k8s.io/api/rbac/v1"`.

It should work.